# Ingore tag using html-proofer with jekyll

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, nokogiri, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a site hosted with github pages built using Jekyll.

One of the plugins I have installed in [html-proofer](https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer).  This was working fine *until* I switched my images to use [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/).

By using Picturefill, I am using the currently invalid `<picture>` tag.  This causes html-proofer to fail when I deploy.

So my question - how can I tell html-proofer to ignore all `<picture>` tags?

My setup:

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
gem 'html-proofer'
```

.travis.yml:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
- 2.1
script: script/cibuild

sudo: false

env:
  global:
  - NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=true # speeds up installation of html-proofer
```

script/cibuild:

```
set -e # halt script on error
bundle exec jekyll build
bundle exec htmlproof ./_site
```

UPDATE:

I've found that it's not actually the `<picture>` element that is causing the problem, but rather the `<img>` tag inside it.  This is because the `<img>` does not have a `src` but rather a `srcset`:

```
<picture>
    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
    <source srcset="examples/images/extralarge.jpg" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
    <source srcset="examples/images/large.jpg" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
    <img srcset="examples/images/medium.jpg" alt="A giant stone face at The Bayon temple in Angkor Thom, Cambodia">
</picture>
```

Adding `data-proofer-ignore` to the `img` tag solves the problem, but I'd rather not have to do this on every instance.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Error logs would be helpful. Running htmlproof on "<picture>" returns successfully.

Comment: "src: Image URL, this attribute is obligatory for the <img> element. On browsers supporting srcset, src is ignored if this one is provided." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

Comment: basszwo: yes - this is an issue with html-proofer rather than my code.  I think I will log an issue if I can't find a better workaround.

Comment: According to W3C's HTML5.1 (<http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-img-element>) `srcset` is not a replacement but rather an optimisation to provide *additional* resolutions. "The src attribute must be present […] The srcset attribute may also be present." In order to be compliant to previous versions *and* quite possibly future versions I recommend adding a `src` attribute.

Comment: This seems to be an issue in Picturefill's sample code …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted an issue on the `html-proofer` repo, where I was told that the `srcset` error is a bug.

Unfortunately, the maintainer indicated that there is no way to ignore specific tags when running the plugin:

See https://github.com/gjtorikian/html-proofer/issues/149